# Permission denied error while downloading a file to remote server using FTP via Jenkins

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting the below error while trying to copy the file from a remote server to another server using ftplib(jenkins job).In my local it is working fine.

In the Python code i'm downloading the text file to the data ware house server and process that file,I'm getting permission issue when downloading that file.Is there a way to process the data in the TEXT file and insert that data to the ware house database without downloading it,If i can do that this error can b resolved.

*1) The part of the python code is also mentioned,Can anyone please let me know how to tackle this, I have FTP access to the source server where the TEXT file resides and SSh root access to the destination data ware house server(Don't have physical access).
Since both are different servers and i'm running it as a job in jenkins, i don't understand which permission need to be checked, which user?
How can i check that with FTP and SSH access?*

2) Also it will be really helpful if someone can guide on how to mention the server, user name and password without hardcoding it in the script.

**Python code:**

```
def getFile(ftp, filename):
    try:
        local_filename = os.path.join(r"/Users/linu/Downloads/", filename)
        #local_filename = os.path.join(r"/home/etl/bi/csv_imports/", filename)
        lf = open(local_filename, "wb")
        ftp.retrbinary("RETR " + filename ,lf.write)
        print("file copied")
    except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
        print ("Error: {}".format(error))
try:
filePath='''/Users/linu/Downloads/log'''
table='staging.stock_dump'

SQL="""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS """+  table + """;CREATE TABLE """+ table + """
(created_date TEXT, product_sku TEXT, previous_stock TEXT, current_stock TEXT );"""

cur_psql.execute(SQL)
cnx_psql.commit()

try:
 ftp = FTP('server.com','username','password')
 print("FTP connection succesful")
 ftp.cwd('/stockitem/')
except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
 print ("Error: {}".format(error))
getFile(ftp,'log')
```

**Error:**

```
12:33:00 [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
12:33:00 Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/log_porting_from_magento/workspace
12:33:00 [workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins34559567899962487.sh
12:33:00 + export PYTHONPATH=/home/etl/bi/
12:33:00 + cd /home/etl/bi/crm
12:33:00 + python3 -u log_porting.py
12:33:00 DWH Connected
12:33:00 Table staging.stock_dump Created at DWH
12:33:01 FTP connection succesful
12:33:01 Error occured while copying file from source to destination 
12:33:01 Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/etl/bi/csv_imports/log'
12:33:01 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: Have you checked your network configuration - any blocked ports or whitelisted ips? Also, if you've configured the server to prevent password access, then you'd need to create an ssh key for jenkins and append its public key to your server's authorized_keys file, and use sftp instead.

Comment: @ToninGuy3n There are several data porting jobs running on the jenkins which ports data from the source server to the data ware house,So i think authorization is not an issue.But it is the first time i'm scheduling a job which requires file permission ,means copying of the file from source to data ware house. So i'm not sure where to check and how to resolve this?  Any guidance will be of great help.

Comment: You could try checking if the `user` you're trying to login as through ftp has read and write permissions to the directory `/stockitem/`. The `/` in front of `stockitem` says that you're trying to access `stockitem` from the root directory. You can view permissions with `ls -la / | grep stockitem`

Comment: @ToninGuy3n Just reiterating so that we are on the same page, Both are different servers,  I'm connecting the source with user via FTP and transfer that file to destination ,the whole process is running via Jenkins job.So what i understood is that the user which i used to connect the source via FTP should also be in the destination and has read/write access to the corresponding folder where i need to paste the file? Is that you mentioned?

Comment: @ToninGuy3n /stockitem/ this  folder is in the source,Inside this folder there is a TEXT file named "log"which i need to copy to the destination server and i'm getting permission denied error while copying the file.

Comment: `ls` is a command you can use on Linux to list directories and files. The `-l` option specifies the read, write, and execute permissions allowable within directory or against the file for users and groups. There seems to be some missing knowledge here if you're not able to understand what I'm referring to.

Comment: @ToninGuy3n i'm not a good linux user, but i do understand  and know basic linux commands, What i have asked is whether the user ,Suppose "XYZ"which i use to connect the source server via FTP need to be created in the destination and should have WRITE access to that folder?

Comment: @ToninGuy3n Can you please let me know which user i have to check, I only have FTP user which access the source server and SSH access which access the destination server. So ftp = FTP('server.com','username','password') , i have to check the permission of this user in the destination server?